# Why does this Ruby code using char.upcase! fail but char = char.upcase works?

Tags: ruby, string, uppercase, lowercase

I was solving a coding problem to do a funny case for each word, "LiKe ThIs". Here was my one liner solution. I know it's a little hacky, but oh well.

```
string.split(" ").map{|word| word.split("").map.with_index{|char,i|
  i.even? ? char.upcase! : char.downcase! }.join("")}.join(" ")
```

This was outputting  `HLO TEE TS` for the input `hello there test`, making it look like only the even case was firing. But on throwing a print statement in there, I can see that yes, it's going through each index.

In my frustration, I changed it to:

```
 string.split(" ").map{|word| word.split("").map.with_index{|char,i|
   i.even? ? char = char.upcase : char = char.downcase }.join("")}.join(" ")
```

which I feel like should be equivalent - changing the char.upcase! to char = char.upcase...And magically, this worked.

What is going on here?

Comment: Just as a note, in your second piece of code, you don't need to assign `char.upcase` or `chat.downcase` to the variable `char`. Simply returning them will work as well (`i.even? ? char.upcase : char.downcase`)

Comment: Thanks Marc, I got mixed up with the upcase! vs upcase, and map automatically assigning it. And Tin-Man - seriously? The formatting answer has nothing to do with my comment, and "code-macho"? I'm a woman, and I was solving some Ruby problems for fun to refamiliarize myself with the language. I found your comment offensive and I flagged it as such.

Comment: "code-macho" has nothing to do with gender. It's a code-condition when people try to use esoteric knowledge to do tricky things that obfuscate the actual processing going on. It's a common issue in Perl and C, where people end up writing so tersely the results become unfathomable for everyone having to work on the code. It's not a good thing to emulate that.

Comment: I'm still not comfortable with the terminology. But point taken about ternary statements, I thought you were saying that they were somehow "OK" in C/Perl, not just that they were more widely used. I appreciate the feedback - would not be using anything like this in a production environment! But for myself relearning Ruby, just trying to get things done. Thanks :) Also, not sure why this question is getting downvoted, but anyone who is downvoting it, please keep this in mind - I haven't programmed in years and I'd like a non judgmental place ot ask questions and learn.

Comment: Some people downvote because they get a whole bag of 'em and think that spreading them around does something useful, not understanding that for every one they use they get one themselves automatically by the system. And, if they use them maliciously, the system will rollback their votes and ding them. Don't worry about them too much; Just ask useful, thought-out questions and the upvotes will roll in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the definition of `upcase!` and `downcase!`. Here's [upcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-upcase-21)

> Upcases the contents of str, returning nil if no changes were made. Note: case replacement is effective only in ASCII region.

Notice that it returns `nil` if no changes were made. In this case, if the character you are iterating over is already in the correct case, it'll return `nil` and effectively remove the character from the string as part of your `map` function.

In your specific example, you'll notice every other character is being removed because it's already in lower case and `downcase!` is returning `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Consider writing your code more clearly:

```
string = 'foo bar'
string.split.map{ |w|
  w.split('').map.with_index{ |char, i|
    i.even? ? char.upcase : char.downcase 
  }.join
}.join(' ')
# => "FoO BaR"
```

Or, even like this:

```
string.split.map{ |w|

  w.split('').map.with_index{ |char, i|
    if i.even? 
      char.upcase 
    else
      char.downcase 
    end
  }.join

}.join(' ')
# => "FoO BaR"
```

Ternary statements should be used judiciously. In languages like C and Perl you'll find them used often, but in Ruby their use is often discouraged, simply because they can be harder to read/understand. If/when you use them, do so with maintenance and readability in mind.

Comment: While I'm sure you meant well, this wasn't an answer to my question. Although this is a simple Ruby problem done to refresh my skills, I'm familiar enough with it to know that oneliners in Ruby are very common, and with that comes the ternary statement.

Comment: It actually does answer the question by showing the correct way to do it. Assigning to `char` inside the innermost `map` in your code accomplished nothing, and probably led to further confusion at that nested level. Keeping the inner `map` as simple as possible always helps to keep things sane. And, it's easy to create a one-liner once a multiple-line, or nested `map` is working correctly. Just remove line-ends; Trying to write it in a single line more often than not gets confusing. It's a situation I point out at work; start simple, getting it working, then reduce as necessary.

Comment: You posted an answer, but you didn't take the time to explain like the other solution and only mentioned formatting. I do appreciate the feedback, but it would help if you focused on the question and then added the formatting issues as an afterthought - thanks!

Comment: The other question had already been selected as an answer, so it appeared that providing additional clarification for fixing your error wasn't needed. I've been doing this stuff for quite a while on SO, and I don't worry about whether I get "the winning answer". I'm more concerned with educating for the long-run, than scoring points.